# Package iPhone-Only binary in robovm

Tags: ios, iphone, libgdx, robovm

I developed a game with libgdx. I already published it to the play store and want to publish it also to the apple store.

Since I want the game to be only available for iPhones I need (or at least I think I need) to package a iPhone-Only binary with robovm...Now it creates only the universal binary which I can't use because the app is not optimized for ipads.

How can I achieve that? Thanks for any hints in advance.

Manuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `UIDeviceFamily` section in your `Info.plist.xml` file to only include `<integer>1</integer>`:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
</array>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just go to you Target settings and change the "Devices" under "Deployment Info" from "Universal" to "iPhone"

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. the problem is that I'm using robovm (an eclipse plugin) to create the binary... (maybe there is a way to repackage the binary?)